# Set Docker's containers on same network as VM

Tags: docker, networking, vagrant, bridge

I have a Laravel environment on a VM provided by Vagrant on the 192.168.33.0/24 network, and created some apps containers on the host for it.

For now, they're communicating using port forwarding and are on the default docker's 172 network, but I need to plug them on the 192.168.33.0/24 network in order to make Gearman PHP Workers share the same .env file values, but I can't make it work.

A bit of google took me here https://qiita.com/kjtanaka/items/f16757c1f0cc86ff225b but it's not exactly what I need, the bridge has to be plugged on the .33.1 interface in my case and from the host. I tried to build some bridges but I can't make it work:

- created a bridge on the host with 192.168.33.1 as gateway using `docker network create`
- plugged the "vboxnet0" .33.33 interface on it
- took my testing redis container using this subnet as 33.101

This way, my container is on .33.101, but my VM isn't even able to ping 33.1 (but still got ssh from the 10.X NAT interface).

Where am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Indeed, I found the solution here. I forgot to change "private_network" to "public_network" in the Vagrantfile :|
Thank you